# cannot execute CVTRES.exe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Could not write to output file 'xxx' -- 'Could not execute CVTRES.EXE.' . I am having this issue. I have re install the VS2010 but yet the problem remains. I have also applied the devnev -resetsettings but in vain. How to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe a permission issue. Check this out: http://dotnetfish.blogspot.fr/2008/01/compiler-error-message-cs0016-could-not.html

Answer (score 5):

I just encountered this issue after installing VS2010 on a VMware image of a customer where I need to debug someting. The error prevented me from building any C# projects, while building C++ projects worked just fine.

The source of the problem was a corrupted `cvtres.exe.config`. I just happened to check out this file:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\cvtres.exe.config
```

and found that it contained nothing but a sequence of zero bytes. After restoring the content of the file from a known good system everything just started to worked fine. Here's what I now have in the file:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <requiredRuntime safemode="true" imageVersion="v4.0.30319" version="v4.0.30319"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku="client" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This answer is probably too late for you, but I'm writing it just in case it will help somebody else. Final notes about my system configuration: Win7 64-bit, VS2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), .NET Framework 4 (4.0.30319 SP1Rel).

Comment: Got this same error in VS2013 Ultimate and this worked well for me! Thank you very much for the XML code the config file is supposed to have and the file path. I even checked on my laptop to make sure the code is standard and it seems like it is.

Answer (score 3):

i resolved this problem by

copied `cvtres.exe` from `framework/v2.0.50727` to `framework/v4.0.30319`

I do't know why but it's work

Answer (score 2):

Again, just in case this is useful for someone else...

I ran into the same problem in Visual Studio 2013. Solution containing project A (a class library with just code) and project B (another class library, this one containing a bunch of resource files), A is referencing B. The exact error is: `Metadata failure while creating assembly -- Could not execute CVTRES.EXE` for project B.

Turns out that A was targetting .NET 4.5 and project B was targetting .NET 2.0. Changing B to 4.5 as well solved the problem. I guess maybe Visual Studio was looking for CVTRES.EXE in a non existing 2.0 related folder or something like this.

**Update:** Indeed, Visual Studio was searching for the file in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` folder and it was not there. Reinstalling the .NET Framework 3.5 (2.0 not available to download anymore) didn't help. I copied the files from a colleague's machine and it worked fine. I don't understand why that happened to me and not to others at my department, we all have the exact same computer setup (Windows 7 Pro x64, VS 2013 Pro).

Answer (score 0):

CVTRES.exe usually complains when a resource .resx file fails to link. Perhaps additional ui language files, etc are the problem. Try compiling excluding those files and see what happens.

Comment: This isn't really an answer

Answer (score -1):

In case someone bumps into issues with cvtres.exe - in my case it was Anti-Virus kicking in, blocking the file from executing.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late, in my case, the CVTRES.EXE file was used by another process, restarting the server solved the problem