# Compiler Error: Could not execute CVTRES.EXE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This is my first time programming in C# and this error popped up when I tried to build solution.

Visual Studio 2012 is working flawlessly with C++ code.

Error Message:

```
Could not write to output file '...' -- 'Could not execute CVTRES.exe'
```

Picture of error:
http://imgur.com/Ud5ledL

Comment: Check out this post - it may be related to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038457/cannot-execute-cvtres-exe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038457/cannot-execute-cvtres-exe

Have you tried that link already?  Seems like a duplicate

Comment: I saw that post, but unfortunately I did not find a 'cvtres.exe.config' file anywhere.

Comment: Cvtres.exe is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319  If you don't see it then your .NET install is borken.

Comment: @HansPassant What should I do to fix my .NET?

Comment: The file is supposed to be there.  It is there on *millions* of machines.  If it is not there on yours then, somehow, a file disappeared without trace from your machine.  That's really rather bad, files are not supposed to just disappear like that.  Feel free to panic, that kind of disappearing act is rarely limited to just one file.  You do have to find out what's wrong with your machine first.  Re-installing .NET is a workaround afterwards.

Comment: My friend just sent me a copy of his 'cvtres.exe' and 'cvtres.exe.config' files and it is building properly now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. Solved it by using .net Framework Repair Tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by manually copying cvtres.exe & cvtres.exe.config from folder

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

to folder

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727